# Wix Managed Application not launching Install

Tags: c#, .net, wix, installation, managed

i am working on a Wix Bootstrapper project where i am trying to make my Managed Application UI.
So now when i am running the `LaunchAction.install` from logs i can see that plan process is completed successfully but it is not applying the install process on packages.

if there is anyone who can help me with that it ll be great.

Thanks

Comment: First it is worth checking if the problem is in your bootstrapper at all. Do you have the same behaviour if you replace your custom bootstrapper with the regular one (like WixStandardBootstrapperApplication)?

Comment: no with default bootstrapper UI it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was Planning the LaunchAction but i wasnt applying it afterwards.
So i added a OnPlanComplete event to my function where i apply the Action after doing some custom stuff.